# Angular e servidor

Tags: spring, angular, cross-platform

Devo ter feito algo de errado, pois voltou a dar o erro.

Criei esta classe:

```
package br.com.netsoft.configuracao.auth;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@Component
public class CrossOriginFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String origin = "http://localhost:4200";
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader(
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,"
                        + "x-gwt-module-base, x-gwt-permutation, clientid, longpush");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Na configuração do spring

> @Bean   public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilterRegistration() {
>         FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new
>   FilterRegistrationBean(
>                 new CrossOriginFilter());       registrationBean.setName("CORS Filter");        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
>         registrationBean.setOrder(1);       return registrationBean;    }

Só que não funciona, sempre dá erro 401, o que pode ser ?

Alguém já passou por isto ?

**Failed to load http://localhost:8080/des-if-web/admin/paisRecurso/pesquisar: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.**

Acessando **http://localhost:8080/des-if-web/admin/paisRecurso/pesquisar**, diretor funciona.

Mais uma descoberta:

---

Acho que o  problema está aqui:

**String requestHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");**

Se preencho a variável **requestHeader** com um token válido, funciona.

Debugando

Navegador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Servidor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não está enviando o browser

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ninguém passou por isto ?

Comment: Ninguém passou por isto ?